# Showup strange space (gap) when use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to build a `BottomSheet` that contains a `RecyclerView` in it. I used a `NestedScrollView` and set its behavior as "bottom_sheet_behavior". The first time the app run, it's popping up normally, but when I collapse the `BottomSheet` and select an item from the spinner, it popping up with a space below it.

This is just happening on android 8, not the other versions.
On the other hand, when I remove `RecyclerView`, it works normally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                    android:background="#c9c5c5"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    android:entries="@array/seasons"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textDirection="rtl" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_Recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[First run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DO5z.png)

[After select an item from spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJqzw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long effort finally found the problem. That was because of using this library ==> [Searchable Spinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner) . I replaced it with simple spinner and it works fine!

> Point:: Always use updated and supported libraries :|